# Node.js - Updating config.js during runtime

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js application with a file named config.json where some credentials are hard coded. My application uses these credentials and I will be deploying my app on AWS so any change to the config.js manually requires me to re-deploy that application. I'm thinking of creating another port where using the 'PUT' operation I can update the config.json. I am not sure if my approach is right, any advice for this problem? I wish to update the config.json file (or just update the json somehow)

EDIT: I don't want it necessarily UPDATE or re-write the file, just somehow use the new credentials without the need of database.

EDIT2: More I think about this, Idk if its possible w/o database. Thoughts?

Comment: What about using environmental variables, resetting those, then just restarting the application.

Comment: Instead of having your hardcoded credentials on a .json file I would advise you to add those configurations to environment variables and access them via `process.env.YOUR_CREDENTIAL`.

Comment: What is the use case? Why would you change credentials at runtime.

Comment: Of course you can programmatically have a mechanism to pass messages to your process which will recreate a new AWS service object with the new credentials but I would recommend using instance profiles to dynamically add/remove capabilities to/from your existing access.